# JSON.parse Unexpected End of Data Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to load data from a mysql database using php and jquery ajax to fill a dropdown list.  But I keep getting errors in firefox and chrome.  The error in firefox is JSON.parse unexpected end of data and in chrome, syntax error unexpected end of input.  I checked the network tab in chrome, but there is no response data.  Please advise.  Thank you.

elihu.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.ajax({            
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/json",         
        dataType:"json",                        
        url:"http://localhost/josiejay/states.php",
        success: function(data) { 
            $("#personalstate").append("<option value='" + data.state_code + "'>" + data.state + "</option>");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " - " + error);
        }
    }); 
});
```

states.php

```
<?php


require('database.php');

function getStates() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM states';

    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $states = $statement->fetchall();
        $statement->closeCursor(); 

        $json_data = json_encode($states); 
        echo $json_data;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$("#personalstate").append("<option value='" +data.state_code                  +                 +'>" data.state + "</option>");` This is where the issue is.

Comment: I changed the code to  $("#personalstate").append("<option value='" + data.state_code + "'>" + data.state + </option>");         But I still get the same error.

Comment: You still missed a quote before "</option>". I think you need to inspect the response data in your browsers developer console, and ensure it's valid JSON.

Comment: There is no response data in the developer console.

Comment: @user3413326 Try this `success: function(data) {console.log(data)}`

Comment: I was unable to get any data using console.log.  However, the problem seems to be json file.  I printed the json_encode file and at the end of the file it has the word 'null'.   {"stateID":"50","0":"50","state_code":"WY","1":"WY","state":"Wyoming","2":"Wyoming"}]null.  I checked my table in the database and there is no field or rows with 'null' value.  I have no idea why null is showing up in the json file.